# How do I write $ad-bc=1$ below $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: latex

```
\Gamma=\Big\lbrace
 \begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\c&d 
\end{pmatrix}: a,b,c,d \in \Z ,  ad-bc=1  
\Big\rbrace
```

I know that "substack" does it but then the formulas are too small.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\underset{<a>}{<b>}` to obtain `<a>` below `<b>`.

```latex
\Gamma=\Big\lbrace
\begin{pmatrix}
   a&b\\c&d 
\end{pmatrix}: 
\underset{ad-bc=1}{a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}}
\Big\rbrace
```